# Creating a dictionary with contents corresponding to the list from among the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = {'Goal': 907.89,'Book': 64.03, 'Tube': 34.12, 'Coke': 153.62, 'Note': 312.86, 'Web':43.21,'Sign':8.02}
b = {'Book', 'Coke', 'Web', 'Lime'}

for key in a :
    if key in b :
        print(key)
    else :
        print()
```

There is a dictionary and a list. I want to complete a dictionary based on the common keys of a dictionary and a list. I know how to find the keys, but it's difficult to create a dictionary with keys and values. I would really appreciate it if you could teach me how. thank you.

The result I want is this.

```
{'Book' : 64.03, 'Coke' : 153.62, 'Web':43.21}
```

Comment: `{k:a[k] for k in b if k in a}` or `{k:a[k] for k in a if k in b}` or `{k:v for k, v in a.items() if k in b}`

Comment: Thank you so much! 
It was a really great help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = {'Goal': 907.89,'Book': 64.03, 'Tube': 34.12, 'Coke': 153.62, 'Note': 312.86, 'Web':43.21,'Sign':8.02}
b = {'Book', 'Coke', 'Web', 'Lime'}

print( {k: a[k] for k in a.keys() & b} )
```

Prints:

```
{'Book': 64.03, 'Coke': 153.62, 'Web': 43.21}
```

---

Note: `b` isn't of type `list`, it's a `set`

Comment: Does & work as an intersection shortcut because keys() returns a set or set subtype?

Comment: @JacobIRR `dict_keys` is not actually a subclass of `set`, but it behaves very similarly.

Comment: @JacobIRR Yes, it's shortcut. `d.keys()` is of type `<class 'dict_keys'>` which implements `__and__`, `__or__` etc. So you can do stuff like `d.keys() & [1, 2, 3]`